# How to call php file via factory/service method using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need to call `php file` using service/Factory method using Angular.js. Here instead of calling `$http` repeatedly in each file to call diferent php file for different purpose, I need to make it common. I am explaining one example below.

> logincontroller.js:

```
var loginAdmin=angular.module('Takeme');
loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$location,$window,inputField){
   $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "php/Login/verify.php",
        data: userData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    });
}
```

I have one common `route.js` file which is common for all controller and given below.

> route.js:

```
var Admin=angular.module('Takeme',['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker','ngMessages','ngCapsLock','ui.bootstrap','ngFileUpload','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('/',{
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
})
Admin.factory('inputField',function($timeout,$window){
    return{
        borderColor:function(id){
             $timeout(function() {
                 var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                 if(element){
                      element.focus();
                      element.style.borderColor = "red";
                 }
             });
        },
        clearBorderColor:function(id){
            $timeout(function() {
                var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
                 if(element){
                     element.style.borderColor = "#cccccc";
                 }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here I need to that `$http service` to call the php file common for which in every controller I will call that `$http` repeatedly. I need to pass only the parameters for `$http service`  and return the response.

Comment: Why do you need to call the php repeatedly?

Comment: Because each time for different db operation I need to call it.

Comment: Although its better to make call from different angular controllers to keep the code modular and maintainable but you can also make the php do the different operations internally and return you the final response but that will again be difficult to maintain and scale.

Comment: @MayankSinghal : Then what should be the better solution for this type of scenario.

Comment: If I am right, you will have different view and functionality after the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create  a factory/service

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('DataService', DataService);

DataService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
function DataService($http, $q) {
return {
    getData: getData,
}
function getData(userData) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "php/Login/verify.php",
        data: userData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error.data);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};
}
```

then use this factory whenever you need in a controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'DataService',  
function($scope, DataService ) {

    $scope.getMyData = function() {
        var data = {};
         DataService.getData(data)
            .then(function(response) {

            }, function(error) {

            });
    };

}
]);
```

Comment: I will test this and let you know.